# jQuery / Html. Cannot unhide and hide a video - but I can hide and unhide it

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a problem that seems illogical. I cannot give a 'hidden' attribute to an embedded video, unless I predetermine it visible.

UPDATE: Looking at the page from inspector, it seems that the width and height values would be suddenly zero. Opacity is 1. Why do the width and height of the video reset, is unclear but probably related to WordPress.

OK, I use jQuery function to hide and unhide text and video:

```
<script>
function unhide (arg) {
   jQuery("." + arg).toggleClass('hidden'); }
</script>
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and then i have HTML

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('videoshow');">click here to show the video</a>

<div class="videoshow hidden">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjKmWk3oE4E" width="460" height="280" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>

<div class="videoshow hidden">
just some random text here.
</div>
```

Guess what? The hidden text will be displayed without any problem, while the video stays hidden. AND if I set

```
  <div class="videoshow">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjKmWk3oE4E" width="460" height="280" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Then the video will be seen in the first place and I can hide and unhide it!
I tried `<video>` instead of `<iframe>` and the results were the same. I tried to place both of the divs to a single table (CSS or Html), but the same thing: what works with the text, does not work with the video.

Comment: Did you try closing that iframe ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, have you just tried using `.hide()` or `.show()` instead of changing the class?

Comment: Is it a typo that you never close the iframe? And have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo </iframe> was missing

Comment: Seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/cL4r1pzx/1/ - just the actual iframe is not loading (as it is blocked by jsfiddle) but as you can see from the placement of the text below it, it is being un-hidden

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Yes, the text has never been problematic, but the video is. If you try it outside jsfiddle, the video will not show up.